# When pages are change it should start from the top of the content

Tags: html, css, reactjs

i made a simple react project with few components/pages. my question here is while i switch between pages(from navbar like home,aboutus, contactus etc) the pages start from where i left them but i want it to start from the top of that page.  I searched but didn't found the term for this thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this code on every route/page change -

```
function scrollToTop() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0; // For Safari
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0; // For Chrome, Firefox, IE and Opera
}
```